# How do I keep scroll position when navigating in a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

have been looking around, but I have not found an answer that helped me out. I am wondering how I can keep the scroll position in a scrollview when I move forwards and backwards in a navigation controller. Currently, when I go to another view in the navigation controller, the scroll view resets and is at the top when I go back. Any code would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if my explanation was not good enough.  So far this is what I have, I know that this won't work, but what should I do?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = scrollSave;
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    CGFloat scrollSave = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: first of all place [super viewWillAppear:YES] method above 
scrollView.contentOffset.y = scrollSave; 
And second, if it didn't help, then try to do that in viewDidAppear method

Answer (score 1):

The code you have above shouldn't even compile. You could save this scroll position in another variable, but generally the scroll position shouldn't be resetting itself anyway. You should remove any code that is trying to manipulate the content offset at all, and see if it restores it to the correct scroll position upon returning to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle's answer should get you storing the variable okay, but in regards to assigning the contentOffset.y, trying animating the scrollview.

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:
CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.origin.x, scrollSave.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height) 
animated:NO];
```

That code would go into viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

With your current approach, scrollSave is a local variable declared in viewWillDisappear so you cannot access the value in viewWillAppear. You will need to create an instance variable or a property. (*If the view controller is still in memory, it should maintain the contentOffset so this might not be necessary*)

```
 @interface MyViewController ()
   @property (nonatomic) CGPoint scrollSave;
 @end

 @implementation MyViewController
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [scrollView setContentOffset:self.scrollSave];
   [super viewWillAppear:YES];
 }

 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   self.scrollSave = scrollView.contentOffset;
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }
```

Now there is an issue with persistence. If the you navigate back in the navigation controller, this view controller will be released from memory. If you need to save the users position then I would suggest using NSUserDefaults.

```
 @interface MyViewController ()
   @property (nonatomic)  NSUserDefaults *defaults
 @end

 @implementation MyViewController
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
   CGPoint scrollSave = CGPointFromString([_defaults objectForKey:@"scrollSaveKey"]);
   scrollView.contentOffset = scrollSave;
   [super viewWillAppear:YES];
 }

 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [_defaults setObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset) forKey:@"scrollSaveKey"];
   [_defaults synchronize];
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }
```

Comment: If I do this scrollView.contentOffset.y is not assignable

Comment: There's no reason to have a property to hold on to NSUserDefaults, which BTW your code never shows where you set this. You can get the NSUserDefaults at any time by calling [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults], which yes is a method call, but it's such a minimal amount of overhead that it doesn't matter. And you wouldn't need to use NSUserDefaults anyway to persist the saved position because if a view controller is still on the navigation stack, it isn't getting deallocated. In fact on iOS 6 and newer, the views don't even get deallocated under low memory, ever.

Comment: I notice you said if you navigate backwards, so yes, in that case you would need to use NSUserDefaults to persist it, but the question talks about going forwards and then backwards, so that doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Gavin the NSUserDefaults property is purely for convenience and aesthetics. The question said "move forwards and backwards" so I took the case when the viewcontroller is popped, it is definitely unnecessary if the VC is still in the nav stack

Comment: @KyleC, it sounds like this is somehow happening when pushing and then popping another view controller. It's generally expected that if somebody goes backwards and then forwards that the view they go forward to will be reset back to the top.

Comment: I am sorry guys, but nothing worked :/ Thank you so much for the help, it is probably me who is doing something wrong or have missed something! @Gavin